# Why the mass minimize the energy?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fluctuation-dissipation

I have been reading the book named "Entropy, Order Parameters and Complexity" and there is an example that confuses me.

[image]

> A mass $m$ hangs on the end of a spring with spring constant $K$ and
> unstretched length $h_0$, subject to a gravitational field of strength $g$. The spring stretches
> to a length $h^*$ where $−mg = K(h^* − h_0)$. At $h^*$ the forces balance and the energy is minimized.

I don't know why at $h^*$ the energy is minimized, doesn't it conserve?

Then the book calculates the average energy of the system(the mass and the spring) in equilibrium using equipartition theorem $$\langle E\rangle = 2\times\frac{1}{2}k_BT = k_BT$$

I wonder why the average energy is so small, I mean in classical mechanics, the potential of the spring is definitely large than $k_BT$.

Comment: Average energy is energy of the system referenced to the equilibrium being 0.